# Combinatorics: Finding a general solution for a recurrence relation.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find a general solution for this recurrence relation:
$$f(n) = 2f(n-1) + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$
when $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$
**EDIT**: n >= 2

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to use generating functions, but it just didn't go well...

Comment: Iz is $$a_n=c_1 2^{n-1}+\frac{2^n \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(n+1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n+1)}-\sqrt{e}\right)}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. This is pure magics !

Comment: Expanding this into an answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark:* If $f(0)=0$, then $f(1)$ must be equal to $-1$, not $1$ as claimed. [Just plug $n=1$ in the recursion]

Multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n\geq 1$
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)z^n=2\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n-1)z^n+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}z^n
$$
and define $\sum_{n\geq 0}f(n)z^n=G(z)$. Hence
$$
G(z)-f(0)=2zG(z)-e^{-z} \left(e^z-1\right)\ .
$$
Using $f(0)=0$, this leads to
$$
G(z)=\frac{ 1-e^{-z}}{2z-1}\ .
$$
The general term $f(n)$ of the recursion can be obtained from Cauchy's formula. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: You are right about that, I forgot to mention that n >= 2. How can it be solved with this?